# verifying the receipt for an auto-renewable subscription

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

When verifying the receipt for an auto-renewable subscription, do i need to encode the shared secret as like we do for receipt_data?

Please let me know

```
{

    "receipt-data" : "(receipt bytes here)",

    "password"     : "(shared secret bytes here)"

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to solve all your confusion https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit

Answer (score 1):

The shared secret is a mere string -- deliver it as-is for the "password" parameter. It's not to be base64-encoded like the receipt.